# Number of pairs of numbers whose product is less than a given number

Tags: c, algorithm

Trying to find a more efficient algorithm to find pairs of numbers whose product is less than the given input.

Tried using the following :

```
                k = N - 1;
        while(k>0)
        {
            div = N/k;
            if(N%k==0)
                div--;
            ans+=div;
            k--;
        }
```

This while it does the job is pretty slow. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Upon some research, this question appears to be related to a [running contest](http://www.codechef.com/APRIL14/problems/CNPIIM) at CodeChef. Quoting their [Code of Conduct](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/18662/does-codechef-have-any-code-of-conduct/18667), "Do not ask or discuss any aspect of any CodeChefs’ problem during an ongoing contest on any other platform, online or offline. Discussion of strategy should be avoided during the contest and postponed till the end." For the spirit of good sportsmanship, I'll remove my answer for until it is over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, if the product of two numbers is less than `n`, at least one of them is less than the square root of `n` (proof by contradiction: otherwise, the product of two numbers not less than `sqrt(n)` is not less than `n`).

So, you can look at all integers `a` up to `sqrt(n - 1)` instead of all integers up to `n`.
For each `a`, count the number of `b >= a` such that `a * b < n`.
Then multiply the result by two to count the pair `(b, a)` for each pair `(a, b)` you saw.
After that, subtract the integer part of `sqrt(n - 1)` to ensure the pairs `(a, a)` were counted exactly once.

For example, when `n = 5`, the eight possible pairs are `(1, 1)`, `(1, 2)`, `(1, 3)`, `(1, 4)`, `(2, 1)`, `(2, 2)`, `(3, 1)` and `(4, 1)`. For `a = 1`, we have `1 <= b <= 4`, so we add 4 to the answer. For `a = 2`, we have `2 <= b <= 2`, so we add 1 to the answer. We get the sum 5. Multiply that by 2 and subtract 2 to get 8.

Comment: I did not completely understand this answer : Like an example if we take the number 5 -> Pairs are (1,1)(1,2)(1,3)(1,4)(2,1)(2,2)(3,1)(4,1). Now if we take one number till sqrt 5 i.e. 1 till 4 and 2 till 2. => total = 6. Now on multiplication by 2 we get 12, subtracted by sqrt(5) we get 10 but the answer is 8. This might be due to my misunderstanding of your answer. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @user3501236: Done. The missing point was that we should consider only `b >= a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with recursion and apply a look-up table if you have multiple queries.

count_all_pairs(n) = count_all_pairs(n-1) + count_all_pair_factors(n-1)